# Is it possible for a Chrome extension to close a current tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible for a Chrome extension to close a current tab that the user has opened? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is, of course, possible for a Chrome extension to close a currently open tab.  The API is [`chrome.tabs.remove()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove).

You must supply the tab ID, or array of tab IDs, which you desire to close/remove as the first parameter.  The second, optional, parameter is a callback function which is called once the tabs are removed.

If you desire to close the active tab in the current window, you may need to obtain that information first.  You can do so with [`chrome.tabs.query()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).  The code would look like:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
    //'tabs' will be an array with only one element: an Object describing the active tab
    //  in the current window. To remove the tab, pass the ID: to chrome.tabs.remove().
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id);
});
```

Comment: I need to close all the tabs with that specific extension only. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Rups, "with" meaning?